# Android: прикасается ли виджет к виджету

Tags: android, java

Есть два imageView.

Их можно двигать пальцем.
И нужно вызывать метод **test()** когда они соприкасаются между собой (налазят друг на друга).

Спасибо.

Comment: Весьма увлекательно. А вопрос то в чём? Вы не знаете, как проверить пересечение двух прямоугольных областей, зная их размеры и положение на плоскости?

Comment: У меня выходит, что они соприкасаются,если один элемент лежит ровно на месте второго.
Их положение вроде как считается по положению (1;1) виджета. А мне нужна вся прямоугольная область =(

Comment: так вы же знаете размеры этих элементов, вот и используйте эти знания. Это простая геометрия.
если знаете положение верхней левой точки элемента, то знаете положение всего элемента.
(1,1) - верхняя левая точка, (1+imageView.getWidth(),1+imageView.getHeight) - правая нижняя точка. и так далее

Answer (score 2):

Есть замечательный метод [Rect.intersect()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#intersect(android.graphics.Rect)) - проверяет текущий `Rect` на пересечение с другим `Rect`

А уж взять `Rect` (то бишь прямоугольник) с виджета, это простите совсем просто...